# Python - Importing a Queue that is regularly updated

Tags: python, queue

idle.py is a file that contains a queue and this queue gets updated every so often (when an email is received, in the example I have largely simplified it but you get the idea):

```
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()
if email received:
    id = email_id
    q.put(id)
```

queuing.py is a file that waits for there to be something in the queue:

```
from idle import q
import time

while True:
    if q.empty() == False:
        number = q.get()
        print "the number is: %s" % number
    print "check queue again"
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem I am encountering is that q.emtpy() is always returning as True in queuing.py even when the queue in idle.py is populated (this can be checked by putting print q.empty() in idle.py).

Comment: I would make idle.py contain a class. Also make sure you assign the queue in idle to a variable in queueing. It appears as though maybe you are accessing different queues.

Comment: It appears I am accessing a different queue is there anyway to access the same queue as was created in idle.py?

Comment: Solution is to get rid of queuing.py and create a thread in idle.py that checks the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general premise of the solution, basically kick off a separate thread that will always be polling the queue.

```
import Queue
import time
import threading

def idle():
    if email received:
        id = email_id
        q.put(id)

def queuing():

    while True:
    if q.empty() == False:
        number = q.get()
        print "the number is: %s" % number
    print "check queue again"
    time.sleep(1)

q = Queue.Queue()
thread1 = Thread(target = idle)
thread2 = Thread(target = queuing)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```